# char array input limit?

Tags: c++, arrays, limit

How do I read in 1000 characters from the console using C++?

**UPDATE from comment on answer: "What i want is that the user can input a paragraph ( say 500 or 300 characters)" - i.e. not always 1000 characters**

With the following code, I am only able to input up to a limit( around two lines). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    char cptr[1000];
    cout<<"Enter :" ;
    gets(cptr);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is for ancient versions of C++ only. You should not use it. Include `<iostream>` instead.

Comment: actually,i am using a pretty ancient version of c++. i have borland c++ 3.0 the problem is all my school computers have this version & they dont update it so i have to code in this way. i have a school project to do for my board exams & it has to run in my school computer so....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int size = 1000;
    char str[size];

    cout << "Enter: " ;

    cin.read(str, size);

    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: @user1819921 `using namespace std;` is pretty much standard in c++.

Comment: Alternative would be to prefix cout, cin and endl with std:: (i.e. std::cout, std::cin, std::endl).

Answer (score 2):

Use `getchar` to read one character at a time in for loop as below:

```
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
              cptr[i] = getchar(); 
            }
```

**EDIT:** If you want to break the loop early e.g. on new line char then:

```
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
                char c  = getChar();
                if(c == '\n'){
                  break;//break the loop if new line char is entered
                }
                cptr[i] = c; 
            }
```

Comment: ,but if i use getchar ,the user will have to input 1000 characters. What i want is that the user can input a paragraph ( say 500 or 300 characters)

Comment: @user1819921: That fine. You can add a type check on the character and break the loop if type matched. Updated the answer with new line check.

Comment: hey,,in d code u gave,i used cin instead of getchar cause i was having some error with getchar. but even then the max i am able to input is 2 lines..dont know why i am having this problem.

Comment: @user1819921: Lets do some troubleshooting. Add statements within the loop to cout the value of `i` once it goes inside `if`. This will tell us, if it entered in the if block? Also, after the for loop, again add the cout to print value of `i` to know, how many times it ran?

Comment: void main()
{
char c,cptr[1000];

int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ cout<<i;
                cin>>c;
                if(c == '\n'){
                  break;//break the loop if new line char is entered
                }
                cptr[i] = c; 
            }
cout<<i;
getch();
}

Comment: the program runs good if i write in short spells like say 1 line,, or a few characters. but when i write more than that,say 2 or 2 & 1/2 lines,it stops accepting more & gets stuck.

Comment: @user1819921 You added cout against each char. Try this: void main() { 
  char c,cptr[1000]; 
  int i; 
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ 
 cin>>c; 
 if(c == '\n'){ 
      cout<<i; 
   break;
 } 
 cptr[i] = c; 
  } 
  cout<<i; 
  getch(); 
 }

Comment: i executed the above code but no output of'i'  was shown. i think the program is having some problem with the new line character .

Comment: @user1819921: Even the last one after the `for` loop didn't print??

Comment: yes. none of the 'i' values got printed. i'm using borland turbo c++ 3.0.

Comment: @user1819921: Looks like its throwing some exception. Wrap your code in  `try-catch` block and print the exception e.g. try {...all your code } catch (exception& e)
  {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  }

Comment: okay, will try that. btw, i need the solution for my project. can you please check it out & tell me where & how i can improve it. a few parts of it are incomplete though. btw,how do i send u my project ? its a bit lengthy and exceeds the character limits here on d commment.

Comment: can u send me ur email id so i can mail u my project ?

Comment: This code is manually implementing [std::cin.getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). `getline` even defaults to using `\n` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the fact that you're reading a new line. `gets(char* ptr)` stops reading when you encounter a new line, and appends terminating character to the string.

Comment: so, how do i solve this ? like say,user wants to input a paragraph of around 300-500 characters

Comment: @user1819921 Call `gets` in a loop until all the input is consumed. On each subsequent call set the pointer to the strings end plus one.

Comment: "set the pointer to the strings end plus one"  did not get this part, can you please write the code for this ?

Comment: @user1819921 Actually, I would recommend just trying the answer using `cin.read`. Assuming you can use `iostream` it is probably much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to user can input a paragraph ( 1000, 500 or 300 characters).

code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  char ch;
  int count = 0;
  int maxCharacters=0;
  char words[1024]={' '};

  cout<<"Enter maxCharacters 300,500,1000 >";
  cin>>maxCharacters;

  cout << "\nProceed to write chars, # to quit: \n";

  cin.get(ch);
  while( (ch != '#')  )
  {
    cin.get(ch);    // read next char on line
    ++count;        // increment count

    words[count]=ch;
    cout <<words[count];     // print input

    if (count>= maxCharacters) break;

  }
  cout << "\n\n---------------------------------\n";
  cout << endl << count << " characters read\n";
  cout << "\n---------------------------------\n";
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++) cout <<words[i];
  cout << "\n"<< count << " characters \n";

  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter maxCharacters 300,500,1000 >10

Proceed to write chars, # to quit:
The pearl is in the river
The pearl

---------------------------------

10 characters read

---------------------------------
 The pearl
10 characters

Press any key to continue
```

Comment: hey ,thnx fr d code.im having a problem, while inputting characters,as soon as i input around 2 lines,further input stops & execution gets hanged. eg : after cout << "\nProceed to write chars, # to quit: \n"; part when say i keep writing & complete around 1 nd 1/2 lines, further input does nt take place . Why am i facing this problem ?

Comment: in 1 go the max i am being able to input is 126 characters, after which further input does nt take place, but if i input multiple times with less that 126 characters,input proceeds normally.